# Missing package for org.apache.http, JAR can't be found

Tags: java

I need the org.apache.http package, where i have tried to use the `find JAR on web` function built inside intelliJ, but no matter, what jar i try to get, it all returns 404 (is this because the package is depricated?)

how is the error i get when i try:
[image]

[image]

Is there any way to get this jar package?

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading it from maven repositories

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.12

Answer (score 0):

If it's a maven project, specify in your pom.xml the repository. And add the dependencies to apache.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo</id>
        <url>https://my repo.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.12</version>
</dependency>
```